# Determine if an infinite series is con- or divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the following infinite series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{4n+(-1)^n}$$

I need to determine whether this sum converges or diverges. The root and ration test were inconclusive as I've tried them and by now I could not come up with a suitable comparable sum. My best guess by now is that it diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let,

$ a_n=\frac{1}{4n+(-1)^n}$

Note that sequence $\{a_n\}$ is monotonically decreasing and $a_n \to 0$.

Hence by Leibniz’s test, above series converges.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
a_n := \frac{(-1)^n}{4n+(-1)^n} = 
\frac{(-1)^n}{4n+(-1)^n} \cdot \frac{4n- (-1)^n}{4n- (-1)^n}
= (-1)^n \frac{4n}{16n^2-1} - \frac{1}{16n^2-1}
=: b_n + c_n.
$$
Now, $\sum b_n$ converges by the Leibnitz criterion, whereas $\sum c_n$ is absolutely convergent. Hence also $\sum a_n$ is convergent.